# jQuery click() handler not working as expected

Tags: java, jquery, function, onclick, click

Here is my jQuery code, but the `click` event doesn't work. Can anyone help me please? I want to slideDown `#menu-drop` after clicking `#menu-oc`. However this code doesn't work for `alert` and any function event.
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(document).on("click", "#menu-oc", function() {
            alert("hi")
        });

        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                jQuery("#header").addClass("fixed");
                jQuery("#header").addClass("goblack", 500);
            } else {
                jQuery("#header").removeClass("fixed");
                jQuery("#header").removeClass("goblack", 500);
            }
        });         

        jQuery("#introcenter").animate({ width: "0" }, 600, function() {
            jQuery(".intro").animate({ height: "0" }, 600, function() {
                jQuery("#main").animate({ opacity : "1" }, 500)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<body> 
    <div id="introcont"> 
        <div id="introtop" class="intro"></div> 
        <div id="introcenter"></div> 
        <div id="introdown" class="intro"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="header"> 
            <button id="menu-oc">MENU</button> 
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header" style="html" />             
        </div> 
        <div id="menu-drop"> 
            <div id="menu">     
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="html" /> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with the `id="menu-oc"`? Can we see your HTML?

Comment: Yes , how i can share my html ?

Comment: ...Paste the relevant section above, we don't need to see the whole file

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different conventions:

- `jQuery/$` usage
- Using the context parameter in one line: `jQuery(document).on("click", "#menu-oc", ...` and then a direct query in another: `jQuery("#header")`
- Your html example isn't complete or at least completely nested, and there are some `<jdoc:include>` elements that I don't know about, but if something is wrong there and they generate a js error for example, it's very hard to know what happens to the rest of the code.

Try cleaning up the code, make it more consistent, remove the `jdoc` stuff to see if you can get a clean simple jquery example to work. Then go from there.

Comment: <jdoc:....> is a code for calling in joomla .  this code work when i use like this >>>> `jQuery(document).click(function(){alert('hello')});`

Comment: Yes, and if that code generates some error it's not possible to see here.

Comment: removed , but still dont working . this click function dont work for any element ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Your example seems simple enough that it should work. Try to change the click event to `jQuery("#menu-oc").on("click", function() { ...`

Comment: now i changed the html , i change the button place from <header></header> to <body></body> and that fixed, and now work . why ?

Comment: Did you use a `<header>` element, not `<head>`? First that was an incorrect name, and second you cannot place an input in `head`. Anything in head isn't supposed to be visible on the page.

Comment: i mean `id="header"` ... not the `<head>` tag

Comment: Ok, well if it works now you should be able to find what breaks it by gradually adding things to the example, and test for each step if it stops working. Good luck, and remember to be consistent when you code. :)

Comment: ok then , thanks and let me know if u find any answer for me.